# Outlook REST API - How to retrieve a User Photo

Tags: c#, outlook, restful-authentication, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I would like to get the photos of my users from outlook and store them in my database. I want it to be done automatically by the programm with no user interaction required, because i know their email and password.

I´m trying to use this guide:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#UseaclientlibrarytoaccesstheOutlookRESTAPIGetanaccesstoken

I have already registered my website (.NET MVC 5), but I don´t know how to do the authentication and access token part, because half of the links of the guide don´t work and i can´t find any helpful tutorial / code snippets somewhere else.

I´m deeply grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Office 365 REST API, we can use the Microsoft Graph.

And since you don't want to the user participate in the authentication, you can using the **Client Credentials Grant Flow** which permits a web service (a confidential client) to use its own credentials to authenticate when calling another web service, instead of impersonating a user.

Here is the REST API to get the photo for a specific user for your reference:

```
GET:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value
```

The app requires one of the following scopes to request the photo of user:

```
User.Read; User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All; User.Read
```

And refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest) to register the app using the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: what is $value? whould we pass a  variable? or plain text $value

Comment: @Diego plain text

Comment: And how about getting thumbnails? /photo('120x120')/$value or /photo/120x120/$value do not work.